# No me autocompletan las etiquetas XSL en Visual Studio Code

Tags: xslt

mi problema es que no se me autocompleta en el archivo .xsl que escribo en VSC pero cuando voy a generar un archivo HTML desde uno XML si que hace la transformación. He estado mirando el PATH de las variables de entorno y creo que las tengo bien puestas. Tengo instalado el JDK y el saxon 10.6 (es el que me obligan a ponerme en clase). He estado preguntando a compañeros que tenian el mismo problema que yo y lo solucionaron reinstalando todas las extensiones, lo intenté pero sigue sin funcionar.

Estas son mis extensiones de VSC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son mis variables de entorno
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la configuracion de la extension "XSL Transform" que me dijeron en clase
(En WordSpace tengo la misma ruta)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias

Comment: No conozco la extensión que tratas de utilizar pero pienso que, con Saxon y XSLT, la mejor opción en Visual Studio Code es https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath, cuya documentación es en https://deltaxml.github.io/vscode-xslt-xpath/. Espero que te ayude.